# SQL PIVOT not as suspected

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I'm working on a data extraction of multiple tables for so far i have this

Table A

| ID | value |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 |

Table B

| ID | FileID | FieldID | A_ID | Data |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | abc |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 123 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | TRUE |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2 | def |
| 5 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 456 |
| 6 | 1 | 3 | 2 | FALSE |

so far I have

```
SELECT Id, Plate, [1] as field1, [2] as field2, [3] as field3 FROM 
   (SELECT A.Id, A.value , B.Data as datavalue, B.Id as dataid
    FROM TableA A, TableB B 
    WHERE A.Id = B.A_ID)as P


PIVOT (MAX(dataid) FOR datavalue in ([1],[2],[3])) as  PVT
```

the answer I expect

| Id | Value | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | abc | 123 | TRUE |

the answer I get

| Id | Value | Field1 | Field2 | Field3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

what am i missing

can't get it figured out

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Perhaps SQL Server?)

Comment: See [Bad habbits](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0):

You need to LEFT JOIN from:
Table B to Table A
instead of
Table A to Table B

Switch the two tables around within the nested select.

Comment: You could improve your answer by citing the corrected query and showing the OP how to write proper SQL-92 join syntax.

Comment: Thanks Stu, do you know how I format SQL in the snippet tool?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Group by` and `Max` function and change pivot code to :

```
PIVOT (MAX(datavalue) FOR datavalue in ([abc],[123],[TRUE])) AS  PVT
```

---

```
SELECT Id, 
       value, 
       max([abc]) as field1,
       max([123]) as field2,
       max([TRUE]) as field3 
FROM 
   (SELECT A.Id, A.value , B.Data AS datavalue, B.Id AS dataid
    FROM TableA A, TableB B 
    WHERE A.Id = B.A_ID) AS P


PIVOT (MAX(datavalue) FOR datavalue in ([abc],[123],[TRUE])) AS  PVT
GROUP BY id,value
```

*Demo in [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=35e66787fcaaad1a1066833933fe53be)*

Comment: I believe he has 1,2,3 fieldIds as constant and known beforehand and not the values like 'abc' etc.

Comment: Yes, this line has a problem in the question. PIVOT (MAX (dataid) FOR datavalue in ([1], [2], [3])) as PVT

Answer (score 0):

I believe you meant B.FieldId instead of B.Id. Other than that you need slight modification (you got the dataId and dataValue wrong, it would be

```
... Max(datavalue) for dataId in ...
```

instead of

```
... Max(dataId) for dataValue in ...
```

Here is revised version:

```
SELECT
  ID, PVT.value, [1] AS field1, [2] AS field2, [3] AS field3
FROM
  (
    SELECT
         A.ID, A.value, B.Data AS datavalue, B.FieldId AS dataid
    FROM TableA            A
         INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.ID=B.A_ID
  ) AS P
PIVOT(MAX(datavalue)
FOR dataid IN([1], [2], [3])
     ) AS PVT;
```

Here is [DBFiddle demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4b206449cd3c109f4b86c2bf61ceab96)